# $.ajax throwing weird "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some jQuery code which is throwing a really weird error. Google Chrome calls the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` and says it is thrown in `c.extend.param.e` of jquery-1.4.4.min.js line 144, but backtraces it to my $.ajax call, which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: target,
   type: method,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: sendData,
   success: function(result) {
       if (result.redirect) {
           window.location = result.redirect;
       }
       else {
           for (var i in result) {
                if ($(i).size()) {
                    $(i).html(result.i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Another question on SO which looks a bit like this attributes it to using `$` without enclosing it in a jQuery function properly, but I'm pretty sure that's not my error this time, because I've been careful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problems is here:

```
event.preventDefault();
var data = $.extend({
    referrer: window.location, <-- window.location is an object,
                                   should be window.location.href
    href: $(this).attr('href')
}, options.linkData);
loadPage(options.linkUrl, options.linkMethod, data);
```

Changing this makes it work, reason it breaks?

```
<jQUery1.4.4 at line 6079>
s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)
```

`encodeURIComponent` does not like the `window.location` object as it only takes `strings`.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: No problem :) Took only 5 minutes (well if you know what you need to look for)

Comment: Where does 
event.preventDefault();
var data = $.extend({
    referrer: window.location, <-- window.location is an object,
                                   should be window.location.href
    href: $(this).attr('href')
}, options.linkData);
loadPage(options.linkUrl, options.linkMethod, data);

come from? The asker didn't include that code in this in his question....

Comment: @ScottDavidTesler, there was a jsfiddle link which was removed because it's dead (sorry). I included the bit I thought was causing the error in the question, but Ivo found the correct part.

Answer (score 2):

try with jQuery.param with traditional parameter in true

[documentation of param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)
[modified](http://jsfiddle.net/7zM8D/22/)

Comment: Thanks, that was another problem. It wasn't the one throwing the error, but you've saved me a lot of head-scratching.